# XMLType Extract Unique ID from Single Cell

Tags: oracle

Can you please help me out to fix the following?

I only required a person_number once eg. 1000142 but I'm getting 10001421000142 like this.

Because the values I have in XML cell have repeating number, so I only want to extract one unique person number.

```
select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ROWSET> 

<ROW0> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
</ROW0>

<ROW0> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> </ROW0> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> 
</ROW0>

</ROWSET>').extract( '//PERSON_NUMBER/text()' ).getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

Comment: select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ROWSET>
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
    </ROW>
  </ROWSET>').extract( '//PERSON_NUMBER[1]/text()' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;

Comment: I have added a new query. by adding the another node with the same person number. Can you please advise me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72291602/1) of the question (where the XML is a valid with a single root element rather than a forest of elements), you can use:

```sql
select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <ROWSET>
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
    </ROW>
  </ROWSET>').extract( '//PERSON_NUMBER[1]/text()' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

Which outputs:

> | P# |
> | --- |
> | 1000142 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3ce233fb2e40e0e9c96e83fb9f0914a6)*

Comment: select xmltype( '<?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> <ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> </ROWSET>').extract( '//PERSON_NUMBER[1]/text()' ) .getstringval() p# from dual;

Comment: I have added a new query. by adding the another node with the same person number. Can you please advise me on this?

Comment: @FarrukhShaikh `/ROWSET/ROW[1]/PERSON_NUMBER/text()`