# XMLType Extract Distinct Value ID from a first node

Tags: oracle

Can you please help me out to fix the following? I only required a person_number once eg. 1000142
but I'm getting 10001421000142 like this.

because the values I have in xml cell have repeating number,
so I only want to extract one unique person number.

```
select xmltype( '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ROWSET> 
<ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
<ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
</ROWSET>').extract( '//PERSON_NUMBER[1]/text()' ) .getstringval() p# from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291602/xmltype-extract-unique-id-from-single-cell#comment127721643_72294164) when you asked this as a follow-up to your previous question, use the XPATH:

```xml
/ROWSET/ROW[1]/PERSON_NUMBER/text()
```

Then:

```sql
select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
      <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
).extract( '/ROWSET/ROW[1]/PERSON_NUMBER/text()' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | P# |
> | --- |
> | 1000142 |

---

If you did want to extract all the `PERSON_NUMBER` values and then find only the `DISTINCT` ones then you can use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p#
from XMLTABLE(
       '/ROWSET/ROW'
       PASSING xmltype(
         '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
         <ROWSET> 
           <ROW>
             <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
             <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
             <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
           </ROW> 
           <ROW>
             <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
             <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
             <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
           </ROW> 
         </ROWSET>'
       )
       COLUMNS
         p# NUMBER PATH './PERSON_NUMBER'
     );
```

Which, for the sample data outputs the same as above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=65470b34f9be0ade7d4c43526c40914c)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this as well:

```
WITH tbl AS
(
  SELECT XMLTYPE( 
                  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
                  <ROWSET> 
                  <ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
                  <ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
                  </ROWSET>'    
                )  xmldata
    FROM dual
)
SELECT node_name, node_value
  FROM tbl
     , XMLTABLE('//*'
                PASSING tbl.xmldata
                COLUMNS node_name  VARCHAR2(100) path 'name()'
                      , node_value VARCHAR2(400) path 'text()')
 WHERE node_name = 'PERSON_NUMBER';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the person number from the first row then your XPath should be:

```
'/ROWSET/ROW[1]/PERSON_NUMBER/text()'
```

instead of getting the first `PERSON_NUMBER` from every `ROW`.

If your XML can have several different person numbers, some or all of which are repeated, then get all of them with XMLTable, and then get the distinct values:

```
select distinct x.person_number
from xmltable(
  '/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing xmltype( '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<ROWSET> 
<ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
<ROW> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER> <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1> <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2> </ROW> 
</ROWSET>')
  columns person_number number path 'PERSON_NUMBER'
 ) x
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=945727a60ba1207c35dabe0bdab0db07)