# How to extract only the subtag in this xml element

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

with this query I can select the content of tag

```
select xmltype(
  '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <ROWSET> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
    <ROW>
      <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
      <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
    </ROW> 
  </ROWSET>'
).extract( '/ROWSET/ROW' ) .getstringval() p#
from dual;
```

> <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1><PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER><LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>

but what I want is to have a list of the sub-tag.

the expected result for this example would be:

> PERSON_NUMBER, LOAN_1

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=39e3733b628ab8a87648153aa5d7235f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [an answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72301562/1509264), you can get the `name()` XPATH value:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT name
from XMLTABLE(
       '/ROWSET/ROW/*'
       PASSING xmltype(
         '<?xml version="1.0"?> 
         <ROWSET> 
           <ROW>
             <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
             <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
             <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
           </ROW> 
           <ROW>
             <PERSON_NUMBER>1000142</PERSON_NUMBER>
             <LOAN_1>25000</LOAN_1>
             <LOAN_2>26000</LOAN_2>
           </ROW> 
         </ROWSET>'
       )
       COLUMNS
         name VARCHAR2(200) PATH './name()'
     );
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | PERSON_NUMBER |
> | LOAN_1 |
> | LOAN_2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aa24af7502a058ef8a93294892bfd4ef)*